# SSRS: Run An Oracle Stored Procedure After A Report Is Rendered

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm working on porting an old PowerBuilder reporting structure to SSRS. A number of the reports were designed as follows:  (This probably isn't ideal, but re-engineering the structure would be difficult.)

1. Run a stored procedure to insert data into a reporting table
2. Query the reporting table and display
3. Run another stored procedure to delete the data from the reporting table

I have #1 and #2 working fine. Not sure on #3--how do I trigger a stored procedure to run after the report has been rendered?

Comment: Why don't you modify your first SP to delete all rows in the table before inserting data on it? That is a common pattern.

Comment: What happens when two people run the SSRS report at the same time?

Comment: Raj More -- there is a session ID that is assigned per user, so we don't have any data collisions.

Comment: Alejandro Zuleta -- that's a great idea! I'd have to tweak it a bit because different users have different session IDs and I wouldn't want to blow away another active session, but if I deleted say all records older than today... that would work.